# Is there anyway to check when an app will be suspended?

Tags: ios, suspend

Is there a universal time of iOS app suspension time (i.e when it goes out of background mode and terminates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background**

> The app is in the background and executing code. **Most apps enter this
>   state briefly on their way to being suspended**. However, an app that
>   requests extra execution time may remain in this state for a period of
>   time. In addition, an app being launched directly into the background
>   enters this state instead of the inactive state. For information about
>   how to execute code while in the background, see Background Execution.

**Suspended**

> The app is in the background but is not executing code. **The system
>   moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before
>   doing so**. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not
>   execute any code. When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may
>   purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the
>   foreground app.

Comment: according to this doc, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle, the state transition should be foreground active -> foreground inactive -> background -> suspension

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not any possibility to know about that, according to this:

> Suspended: ...The system moves apps to this state automatically and **does not notify** them before doing so...

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html